# Finding centroid of a polygon with holes

Tags: geometry, polygons, centroid

I am able to find the centroid of a polygon *without* holes. How can I find the centroid of a polygon with holes?

Comment: Did you try to divide it up into smaller polygons without holes, finding their centroids and averaging them?

Comment: thanks for ur reply . did u mean dividing the actual polygon.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the area of the polygons, you can use the weighted average of the containing and internal polygon centroids. Specifically, if the two polygons have areas $A_{out}$ and $A_{in}$, and centroids $\bf r_{out}$ and $\bf r_{in}$, the centroid of the polygon "doughnut" will be:
$$\frac{A_{out}{\bf r_{out}} - A_{in}{\bf r_{in}}}{A_{out}-A_{in}}$$

Comment: thanks for your reply actually i have inner polygons more than 3  kindly see the link https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5Vh2tWJlQW_WUJGaV9COU1NbE0/edit

Comment: @Suri - the formula should still work - just replace $A_{in}r_{in}$ with $A_1 r_1 + A_2 r_2 + \ldots$

Comment: Will the centroid comes outside the inner polygon or inside . i tried with the above formula but the centroid is coming inside the innerpolygon.